# AngularJS directive transclusion

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Check out this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acajic/DGpCc/1/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <interactive-table row-selected="onRowClickFunction">
        <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.points}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Peter</td>
                <td>154</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dan</td>
                <td>141</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </interactive-table>
</div>
```

Module, Controller, Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  "use strict";

  $scope.users = [{
      name: "Jane",
      points: 152
  }, {
      name: "Robert",
      points: 171
  }, {
      name: "Valerie",
      points: 163
  }];

  $scope.onRowClickFunction = function (name) {
      alert(name);
  };
});
app.directive('interactiveTable', function () {
  "use strict";
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      rowSelected: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(element); // EDIT #1: inserted

      $(element).find("tr").click(function () {
        alert("bravo");
        //scope.rowSelected("jakost");
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I called it "interactive table". It is just supposed to be a table that enables rows selection, notifies you when row is selected and changes style for selected row.

Whether or not this is the best approach to create interactive table is irrelevant.
I am trying to learn more about directives.

Questions for this JSFiddle:

1) Only the static rows (Peter & Dan) respond to click events. How to put click listeners on generated rows (Jane, Robert, Valerie)?

2) Currently I have to wrap my *table* tag with my *interactive-table* tag. It would be great if I could just mark a *table* to become "interactive".

3) Finally, is there a better way to have a simple table element that will notify you when some rows or elements were selected, that would change style of rows that are selected, etc.
Also, are there some simple AngularJS directives like this available for download? Do you have any favorites?

**EDIT #1:**

Added console.log(element) inside directive code.
It prints out DOM element with innerHTML property looking like this:

```
<div ng-transclude="">
            <table style="border: 1px solid black;" class="ng-scope">
                <tbody><!-- ngRepeat: user in users --><tr ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
                    <td class="ng-binding">Jane</td>
                    <td class="ng-binding">152</td>
                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: user in users --><tr ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
                    <td class="ng-binding">Robert</td>
                    <td class="ng-binding">171</td>
                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: user in users --><tr ng-repeat="user in users" class="ng-scope">
                    <td class="ng-binding">Valerie</td>
                    <td class="ng-binding">163</td>
                </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: user in users -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>154</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Dan</td>
                    <td>141</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
```

I figured that first three rows weren't generated at the time click handler was being configured. This result is confusing for me because the DOM element printed clearly stated that it has 5 rows before .click handler was set. But I don't want to get into that.

Where do you suggest I put ng-click? On *tr* tag? The whole purpose of this is that I have unaltered html code inside directive, and directive ALONE adds behaviour to the content of the directive.

Comment: Be aware that when calling `console.log` passing in a reference, the console window will be `updated dynamically`. When you call this function, the rows are actually `not generated yet`. You could check this by `alert(element[0].outerHTML);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you attach event listeners using `$(element).find("tr")`, the `<tr>`s are not generated by angular yet. You could try jQuery delegated event handler or `ng-click` (more recommended)

2) You just need to set the directive as a property on the table and set the restrict to include A (attribute)

```
restrict: 'EA'
```

3) You could use `scope.$emit` to notify if a row is selected.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M66Jy/)

If you need to bind function, try:

```
row-selected="onRowClickFunction(name)"
```

And call it like this:

```
scope.rowSelected({name:"abc"});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M66Jy/1/)

Comment: OK, regarding question #1, delegated event handler is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks ;)

For #2: using an attribute is a little bit cleaner and I will go with this. But still, I don't see why there must be a DIV element inside my table... I mean, If I put it on some legacy HTML code that has "table tbody" jQuery selector attached. It would become broken, because now some DIV is inserted in between TABLE and TBODY.

Comment: @ancajic: just remove the template and transclude as in my second demo. In the first demo, I forgot to remove them.

Comment: Just for the record, this last JSFiddle... Does not work with AngularJS 1.2.0.

Couldn't figure out the problem for some time now. It works in JSFiddle, but the exact same thing does not work on my computer. Upgraded to AngularJS 1.2.13 and works great.
@KhanhTO, if you feel like it, you can shed some light on this, too... :)

Comment: @ancajic: angular 1.2.0 and angular 1.2.13 should not have much difference. Do you have any errors in the console?